# xpath - clicking all buttons

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath

My code goes into a webpage, and this page has rows of records. Each row when clicked, shows a drop down.

My code initiates a click, **but only for the first row of the webpage** for some reason?

How can i get my code to when it comes across each and every record, to perform a click. And not just for the first entry?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(f'https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=24&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page=1')
time.sleep(4)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='accordin_title')
for j in productlist:
    title=j.find('h4').text.strip()
    buttonToClick=driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign')
    buttonToClick.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign')` command is searching for the first element having `sign` class name on the entire page. This is why this always will give you the same, the first element. While you should search **inside** the `j` element.
The same about the `h4` title.
In order to get the title and click on buttons **inside**  the accordions try this:

```
productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='accordin_title')
for j in productlist:
    title=j.find_element_by_xpath('.//h4').text.strip()
    buttonToClick=j.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="sign"]')
    buttonToClick.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

**UPD**
Let's try pure Selenium solution

```
driver.get(f'https://library.iaslc.org/conference-program?product_id=24&author=&category=&date=&session_type=&session=&presentation=&keyword=&available=&cme=&page=1')
time.sleep(4)

productlist_length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='accordin_title']"))
for i in range(1, productlist_length+1):
    product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='accordin_title'])[" + str(i) + "]")
    title = product.find_element_by_xpath('.//h4').text.strip()
    print(title)
    buttonToClick=product.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="sign"]')
    buttonToClick.click()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Hm, the xpath for the title variable seems to show an error.

however, the xpath for the buttonToClick works with this .// format, but with driver.find_element_by_xpath. However, similar to my problem, it only clicks on the first row for some reason...

Comment: What is the actual content of `productlist`? Can you debug and say me?

Comment: Product list holds the information content for each row such as title information. This prints fine with my original code (non xpath)

For debugging - buttonToClick=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="sign"]') works for me, but only for the first row as well

Comment: I understand what it should hold. I'm asking about the actual data. can you put a breakpoint on line `title=j.find_element_by_xpath('.//h4').text.strip()` and then see what is the content of `productlist`? Does it contains web elements and if yes - how many?

Comment: productlist contains about 6 web elements, 
title=j.find_element_by_xpath has the error -> 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: OK, I will try to make all this with selenium without mixing with bs. Hope this will work.

Comment: Ah this works beautifully. I did not expect a mix of bs and selenium or even purely bs to be less effective than selenium in this case. Great help, thank you!!